# J2ME Registration Screen

Tags: java-me

I would like to add some kind of Registration Screen to my J2ME software in order to allow users to use my app for a trial period and only give them full access after registration.
I know how to get the IMEI etc. but I wonder if there is already code out there which handles the generation of a unique phone identifier and creation of some kind of "CD-Key" for J2ME...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a lot of downloadsites use(handango etc), is the RPN registration method.
Given a unique ID (IMEI on phones, ownerid on PocketPC, etc) you do a calculation on it which is unique for your app (for instance: add all letters together and divide by 5). This number is your unlock code.

now the user who wants to register your app, gives it's imei number to the webstore,... they pay,... and the webstore does your unique calculation. It then return the unlock code to the customer.

The customer inputs the unlock code into your app, if it matches then they payed!

The way to store this unique calculation is by virtue of RPN (Reverse Polish Notation). This is a way like how HP calculators worked. Instead of typic 4*3 and getting the answer 12, you type: 4 3 *

here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/Reverse_Polish_Notation.aspx) on the PocketPC implementation of how to implement the RPN method yourself. Lot's of webshops have the RPN calculator in their webbackend so this way you become compatible with them.

Comment: Which webshops do you know for j2me which use this method? (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789379/best-portal-so-buy-and-sell-j2me-apps)

Comment: ralf: as I said I know for sure handango uses this method (and they sell j2me (they have j2me portals for big carriers)), as do other shops. Most shops I used was for Pocketpc and Symbian sales (pocketgear, mobile2day) and they all used RPN. If you have a site where you want to sell your product, just ask if tehy support it too.